# Google Maps Android Application not working correctly

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've created this Android application based on GoogleMaps, but when I try to run it on my smartphone (Huawei P8 Lite), sometimes it runs correctly, but sometimes (most of the time) I get the error saying that "Unfortunately, the application stopped". I don't know why it can both run correctly a couple of times and then it stops working and won't open....

This is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.francydarkcool.maps">

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<string android:name="xxxxx">11111</string>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.francydarkcool.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.francydarkcool.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the MapsActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.francydarkcool.maps;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the MapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }

        }
    });

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    //Do a null check to see if the map is not already instantiated
    if (mMap == null)
        //try to obtain the map from the MapFragment.
         {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                if (mMap != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    //check if successful
    if (mMap != null) {
        setUpMap();
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.402850, 25.518595)).title("unu"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.402856, 25.518608)).title("doi"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.402834, 25.518772)).title("trei"));

    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(myLocation != null){
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    else
    {
        Location   getLastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = getLastLocation.getLongitude();
        double latitude = getLastLocation.getLatitude();
    }

    //set map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    //Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Show the current location in Google Maps
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    //Zoom in GoogleMap
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
}
}
```

And the reeeealy big logcat:

```
03-07 13:18:59.900 30222-30222/com.example.francydarkcool.maps E/ZipFileCache: init failed when open zip file.
03-07 13:18:59.900 30222-30222/com.example.francydarkcool.maps E/ZipFileCache: init failed when open zip file.
03-07 13:19:00.080 30222-30222/com.example.francydarkcool.maps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.francydarkcool.maps, PID: 30222
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.francydarkcool.maps/com.example.francydarkcool.maps.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2406)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.francydarkcool.maps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:29)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6013)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The activity_maps.xml file:

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.francydarkcool.maps.MapsActivity" />
```

And the strings.xml file:

```
 <resources>
 <string name="app_name">Maps</string>
 <string name="title_activity_maps">Map</string>
 <string name="google_app_id">xxxxxx</string>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Which line is the line 57?

Comment: @tinysunlight mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: findFragmentById returns null in this case. You call getMap on null object. NPE is thrown. **a)** Please use `getMapAsync` instead of `getMap`, it's been out for two years now. **b)** Make sure there is a fragment going by ID `@+id/map` in your activity layout.

Comment: @EugenPechanec it says: "getMapAsync in MapFragment cannot be applied to <PROJECT NAME>.MapsActivity

Comment: The parameter supplied to `getMapAsync` needs to implement [`OnMapReadyCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback).

Comment: @EugenPechanec I've updated the code, but now it gives me the error: "Wrong 1st argument type.Found 'com.google.android.gsm.maps.OnMapReadyCallback' required 'android.content.Context'" on this line: "if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    .... } "

Comment: @EugenPechanec I've updated the code, but now the application won't start at all....

Comment: Which brings us back to the real issue **b)** Make sure there is a fragment going by ID `@+id/map` in your activity layout.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I've written this code: "<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map" /> " but now it tells me that 'fragment' is not declared...

Comment: a) `<fragment name="...">` not `class="..."` b) Fix your MapsActivity code. MapFragment is not the same as SupportMapFragment

Comment: @EugenPechanec Modified. I still get an error: "Element fragment must be declared" : <fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.francydarkcool.maps"
    name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map" >

Comment: @EugenPechanec sorry, it was in the wrong folder. I've moved the fragment in the layout folder

Comment: Refer to this http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout

Comment: It still doesn't work... I've updated the Logcat

Comment: Does your activity_maps layout actually contain the R.id.map fragment??

Comment: Please post the layout in the question, it's hard too read in the comments. Also make sure you don't have multiple versions of the layout and where some of them are missing the fragment.

Comment: Run it again: now I have only one error: "E/ZipFileCache: init failed when open zip file."